# Add every n number to the previous one

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve this problem in python. The problem is the following:

I have a list of integers that looks like this

```
[5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2]
```

The goal is to make an addition every two number, and add them to the first two. For example,
The first two numbers are **5, 12**. For the number 5, I want to add 4 and 8, thus having in total 5+4+8 = 17. The same thing I would do for 12, 12+6+2 = 20.

That is the main concept of this problem. Is there any way I can generalize it? For example, for a list [4, 2, 3, 1 , 5, 6], I would have 4+1 = 5, 2+5=7, 3+6 = 9.

Edit:

The whole idea is I would set an initial gap for example 2, and based on this gap I would make the addition. In the first example I have a gap of 2, that's why I add 3 numbers, while in the second I have a gap of 3, that is why I add 3 numbers.

The final output for each example is this:

Example 1

```
[17, 20]
```

Example 2

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

I there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please explain it more specifically? For the first question, you added every number with a gap of 1, and for the next example, you added numbers with a gap of 2. So is the gap a variable?

Comment: Are you sure about the second example? shouldn't it be `4+3+5` and `2+1+6`? what is the logic

Comment: @Mathpdegeek497 Sorry about the confusion. I made an edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: @TomRon Sorry about my bad explanation. I made an edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: @CostasGinos please add the final output list and also what you wanted it to look like. I am still not getting your point.

Comment: @Mathpdegeek497 I just did

Comment: @CostasGinos great, that helps, and now you also have various correct answers to this also. Those will surely help you.

Answer (score 3):

You want to build a list of sums of sublists. You can use:

- [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to build the list;
- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum);
- [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=slice) to build the sublists.

```py
def interleaved_sums(l, k=2):
   return [sum(l[i::k]) for i in range(k)]

print(interleaved_sums([5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2]))
# [17, 20]

print(interleaved_sums([5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2, 1]))
# [18, 20]

print(interleaved_sums([4, 2, 3, 1 , 5, 6], 3))
# [5, 7, 9]
```

---

You've asked for other, more cumbersome ways to write these sums without the slicing notation:

```py
def interleaved_sums2(l, k=2):
    return [sum(l[j] for j in range(i, len(l), k)) for i in range(k)]
    # replace "l[i::k]" with "l[j] for j in range(i, len(l), k)"

def interleaved_sums3(l, k=2):
    return [sum(l[i + k * j] for j in range(len(l) // k + (i < len(l) % k))) for i in range(k)]
    # use only range(stop) instead of range(start,stop,step) but this is awful

def interleaved_sums4(l, k=2)
    return [sum(x for j,x in enumerate(l) if j % k == i) for i in range(k)]
    # less efficient: has to try every element instead of only appropriate elements
```

Comment: Thank you!. Is there any way i can do it without using that syntax **l[i::k]**.

Comment: @CostasGinos You could do `[sum(x for j,x in enumerate(l) if j % k == i) for i in range(k)]` but it's slightly less efficient as it iterates on every element instead of only the relevant elements

Comment: @CostasGinos Or `[sum(l[i + k * j] for j in range(len(l) // k + (i < len(l) % k))) for i in range(k)]` but look how complicated it is to find the correct range for j when doing this

Comment: @CostasGinos Or `[sum(l[j] for j in range(i, len(l), k)) for i in range(k)]` but here I've just replaced `l[i::k]` by `l[j] for j in range(i, len(l), k)` so I really don't see the point. Why do you want to avoid `l[i::k]`? It's very appropriate for this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! .. I will use the first alternative way you gave me.. One more thing, is there any way I can use sum() with the old fashion way, for example something like $array[$i]+=a_value ?

Comment: @CostasGinos The whole point of `sum` is to avoid doing this "old fashion way". If you want to do it the old-fashoned way, then do not use function `sum`. Do it yourself. Yes, of course it's possible. Don't use `sum`, use regular loops `for j,x in enumerate(l): ...`

Comment: What if the given list is ```L = [5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2, 1]```  and ```k = 2``` then?

Comment: @DanielHao I think all the different options I have written all return `[5+4+8+1, 12+6+2]`. The OP only gave examples where the number of items in the list was a multiple of `k`, but I assume this is what should be returned in that case. This is why trying to avoid the `step=k` parameter, either in `l[i::k]` or in `range(i, len(l), k)`, is a bad idea in my opinion, and results in the awful `[sum(l[i + k * j] for j in range(len(l) // k + (i < len(l) % k))) for i in range(k)]` where I have to use modulo to figure out the exact index of the last element.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a copy of the list only containing every Nth number by `lst[0::N]`

In your case would that result in something like:

```py
numbers = [5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2]

print(sum(numbers[0::2]))

print(sum(numbers[1::2]))
```

Where the first parameter in the `[]` is the starting point and the second one the Nth number you want.

Comment: @Stef I have renamed it to `numbers`

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate on gap and use the same gap for hop while doing `sum`

```
nums = [5, 12, 4, 6, 8, 2]
gap = 2

for i in range(gap):
    print(sum(nums[i::gap]))
```